# y-axis of chart.js charts is scrambled

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

So I'm generating graphs with chart.js. For some reason, the Y-axis is completely scrambled which makes no sense! Would anybody know how to fix this? Here's my code:

[image: graph generated by chart.js]

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var chartDataSource2 = {{ json_encode($micromarket_participants) }};


        $(function () {
            $("#chartContainer2").dxChart({
                dataSource:                 chartDataSource2,
                commonSeriesSettings:       {argumentField: 'id'},
                series:                     [      
                                                {
                                                name:       'minSingleCareFee',            
                                                valueField: 'minSingleCareFee',
                                                type:       'bar' 
                                                },                                           
                                            ]
            });
        })


</script>

    <div id="chartContainer1" style="height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

im just having the same with u and i found what the problem is. hope its useful for u.

error may occur in the datasource
for numbers, u have to pass the array to the chart.js function without any ""

for example,
dataSource = [{time:"08:00", a: 10, b :10}];

but not
dataSource = [{time:"08:00", a: "10", b :"10"}];

then the y-axis would come back! :)